# Drupal 7: Display Latest Revision's Author on the Admin Content Overview page with Admin Views Module

Tags: views, nodes, users

Does anyone know the methodology to display the author of the latest content revision, using the Admin Views module on the content overview page (e.g. /admin/content)?

It's easy enough to display the initial author, or the VID of the latest revision, but I'm not sure how to create the relationship to the author of that latest revision and then display it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a relationship (Advanced > Relationships) for "Content Revision: User". Make a note of the name of the relationship.

Add a field for "User: Name" and then make sure the relationship matches that of the relationship you added.